# How to encrypt LDAP UserStore password in usr-mgt.xml in WSO2?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I am trying to encrypt the `UserStore` connection password in WSO2 Identity Server (usr-mgt.xml) using `ciphertool.bat` ( using WSO2 version 5.0.0).

I have a `jks` file with same password for `key` and `keystorepassword`. In `ciphertool.properties`, modified following line as:

```
UserStoreManager.Property.ConnectionPassword=repository/conf/user-mgt.xml
```

I generated a encrypted password by using `ciphertool.bat -DConfigure` command and I updated `ciphertext.properties` file as:

```
UserStoreManager.Property.ConnectionPassword=RG1Bz7q0VbyTLJ3t2yCKaoquXkZZ0XrgKZ8PgsYp4F4NNiIJ4c16aCEa2AkdYFL+jaPVmbOF/lFK1A0EWFXO35UsQ28DkwtiDKw9er4USm3DML9OlG+Ve/QNXF3RoiLG00DJGeRrqFTuz5SpphGJk1ShidEYvIyzx/5KK4BK1r0CHfMTqNFvwwAr8QY6uUD/bgbn8T99LrleRJu6fA76l77CaruISBdtf/bx1BdE30xN/+OJ5l3R9qrswLNEafxPRiHcvwuHP5BI31m6WiZ/6zUt5+P0NYCYF8aw7qNPt99+z5KAzslrk1pV3fOIirs7skhGwWDuayMa6HUU5f9CyA==
```

Not sure how I should tell the `usr-mgt.xml` file to use encrypted password. I just tried updating properties file as `<Property name="ConnectionPassword">RG1Bz7q0VbyTLJ3t2yCKaoquXkZZ0XrgKZ8PgsYp4F4NNiIJ4c16aCEa2AkdYFL+jaPVmbOF/lFK1A0EWFXO35UsQ28DkwtiDKw9er4USm3DML9OlG+Ve/QNXF3RoiLG00DJGeRrqFTuz5SpphGJk1ShidEYvIyzx/5KK4BK1r0CHfMTqNFvwwAr8QY6uUD/bgbn8T99LrleRJu6fA76l77CaruISBdtf/bx1BdE30xN/+OJ5l3R9qrswLNEafxPRiHcvwuHP5BI31m6WiZ/6zUt5+P0NYCYF8aw7qNPt99+z5KAzslrk1pV3fOIirs7skhGwWDuayMa6HUU5f9CyA==</Property>`

This fails. Apparently it works when I use `unencrypted` password. This means the `usr-mgt.xml` file fails to understand that it should read the password as encrypted.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be you missing the order. First you need to update the `ciphertext.properties` file according to your requirement. After that you can run the **ciphertool.bat -DConfigure** command and encrypt the password.

P.S. - This [blog entry](http://xacmlinfo.org/2012/08/12/secure-plain-text-passwords-in-wso2-carbon-configuration-files/) help you more about **Secure Vault**.

Comment: I have done the same. My question is how to write encrypted password in `usr-mgt.xml`? Is it automatically written? if yes then it is then it is not working. I have manually copied the encrypted password in `usr-mgt.xml` as shown above but it does not work.

Comment: what is happen in internally, when run the `ciphertool.bat -DConfigure` your `ciphertext.properties` files you update properties value are encrypting. Please checked with your enter value in `UserStoreManager.Property.ConnectionPassword=[youentered_passwd]`. please check above blog entry ,it explain more details.