# WSO2 APIM encrypt credentials for multiple gatways

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Following [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55336334/wso2-encrypt-the-primary-ldap-userstore-credentials/55370845#55370845) - having WSO2 APIM 2.6.0 with multiple gateways (internal, dmz), we'd like to encrypt credentials for the gateways.

My idea is to achieve something like:

api-manager.xml

```
        <Environment api-console="true" type="hybrid">
            <Name>Internal</Name>
            <Description>Internal GW</Description>
            <ServerURL>https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}${carbon.context}services/</ServerURL>
            <Username>admin</Username>
            <Password svns:secretAlias="APIGateway.Internal.Password>password</Password>
            <GatewayEndpoint>https://internal-host:8243</GatewayEndpoint>
            <GatewayWSEndpoint>ws://${carbon.local.ip}:9099</GatewayWSEndpoint>
        </Environment>
        <Environment api-console="true" type="hybrid">
            <Name>External</Name>
            <Description>DMZ GW</Description>
            <ServerURL>https://dmz-host:9444${carbon.context}services/</ServerURL>
            <Username>admin</Username>
            <Password svns:secretAlias="APIGateway.External.Password">password</Password>
            <GatewayEndpoint>https://dmz-host:8244</GatewayEndpoint>
            <GatewayWSEndpoint>ws://${carbon.local.ip}:9099</GatewayWSEndpoint>
        </Environment>
```

cipher-tool.properties

```
APIGateway.Internal.Password=repository/conf/api-manager.xml//APIManager/APIGateway/Environments/Environment[Name='Internal']/Password,false
APIGateway.External.Password=repository/conf/api-manager.xml//APIManager/APIGateway/Environments/Environment[Name='External']/Password,false
```

With a single gateway it's pretty easy and it's working - we can define an `APIGateway.Password` property to be used with the *ciphertool*. The property is already predefined in the cipher-tool.properties (commented out by default)

For me it is strange that the alias name is somehow depends on the XML Path, we cannot use any alias name. Even renaming the alias to  `APIGateway.Environment.Password` (or APIGateway.Internal.Password) causes password not to get resolved. **Any idea what are the alias naming rules?**

When having multiple gateways defined for a publisher - how could we distinguish the secret aliases for multiple gateways? It definitely works for datasources somehow. I can define the aliases in the cipher-tool and cipher-text, the credentials are getting properly encrypted, but apparently not resolved

Is even possible o have credentials encrypted for multiple gateways? Did I miss/misunderstood any naming rules? Or should I just search for typos in my config?

Comment: you have to set alias in two files: `cipher-text.properties`
    and `cipher-tool.properties`

Comment: @daggett I did, it's working for a single gateway with specific alias name. If I use different alias names for 2 gateways, I am unable to publish any API (failed authentication)

Comment: have you changed both files? if, yes please add to your question the changes to `cipher-text.properties`